# PHP Change linux user password (passwd)

Tags: php, linux

i want to change user passwords via my api, but my current code doesnt work.

Maybe someone could help me.

```
$cmd1 = "passwd ".$info['instanceFtpUser'];
$ssh->exec($cmd1."\n");
$ssh->exec($newpass."\n");
$ssh->exec($newpass."\n");
$ssh->disconnect();
```

btw, i'm using phpseclib

Comment: You need only one `exec` call, the password needs to be passed as input to the `passwd` command, not sent as separate commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is an example on the phpseclib docs:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html

As you can see you above you should use `write` to output to PTY, not `exec`:

```
$ssh->enablePTY(); 
$cmd1 = "passwd ".$info['instanceFtpUser'];
$ssh->exec($cmd1);
echo $ssh->read('password:'); 
$ssh->write($newpass."\n"); 
echo $ssh->read('password:'); 
$ssh->write($newpass."\n");
$ssh->disconnect();
```

Comment: Getting a error at the second password thingy.

Enter new UNIX-Password: TrFBomqf0UTB

root@n3525325325252352523:~# TrFBomqf0UTB -bash: TrFBomqf0UTB: Command not found.

Comment: If your `passwd` do not forces you to retype new password (which happened to you as I understand from the trace above) you can omit the second `read` and second `write` from my example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sshpass (https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) it lets you ssh to a remote server without asking for password. you can create a script that ssh to the remote server and sets the new password. you can then call this script using the php exec function.